# What method is called on the fragment when the navigation drawer is opened?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I need to run some specific methods on the fragment when the navigation drawer is opened and closed. Are there any methods that I need to override in the fragment class in order to achieve this?

Tried `onResume()` and `onPause()`, but seems they are not called when the navigation drawer is on top of the fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the navigation drawer doesn't have anything to do with the fragment's lifecycle, so there isn't a method you can just override for this. You can set a listener in the DrawerLayout with [setDrawerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerListener%28android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener%29) to be notified when the drawer state changes.

Comment: So every time the navigation bar is opened by dragging, the navigation drawer fragment is invoked by calling its onCreateView() method.

Is this false?